# In similar queries: to get System.InvalidCastException or not to get

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I want to get a decimal value from DB into a variable. I'm getting

> System.InvalidCastException: Specific cast is not valid

from this query:

```
var result = Connection.Places.First(d => d.ID == 6).Rate;
```

However, I'am not getting any error from below method:

```
var result = GetRate(6);
public decimal GetRate(int id)
        {
            return (from d in conn.Places
                    where d.ID == id
                    select d.Rate).First();
        }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Places table design is here:

[image]

Comment: What is the type of the property ID?

Comment: ID property's type is integer and Rate type is decimal(9,2)

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidCastException` says there is a `convert` issue. It's probably because `GetRate(int id)` can't convert the result into the `decimal` data type. try to retrieve the result at first, then convert it into the `decimal` data type, then return the result

Comment: GetRate() method returns true result. Problem is in first query -> var result = Connection.Places.First(d => d.ID == 6).Rate;